# Web Filter For Multiple Networks

Tags: webfilter

I have been using a Barracuda web filter 310 in our network and I have just had enough of it. It does not support trunking and we have several networks that have users that need to be web filtered. (I guess if everyone just did their flippin jobs I would not have this issue) but the management wants me to get it resolved.

Does anyone know the top five web filters that are better than the barracuda web filters that support network trunking so that I can have multiple domains and subnets going through it?

Thanks in advance - everyone on this site is gold in my book!

Comment: Nothing? no one know anything about web filters?

Comment: [Product and Service recommendations are off-topic on all stack exchange sites.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 1):

We went with the BIG-IP's from F5.com the best on the market.

Answer (score 0):

We've Used the Bloxx 1250 Web appliance for a few years now that supports subnet management which has made my job a lot easier.

You should give them a look at - www.bloxx.com